# Раннее просмотренные товары Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Интересует есть ли готовый функционал "Раннее просмотренные товары" в Yii2.
Интересует какой-нибудь виджет или что-то в этом направлении.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типичный функционал, пишешь в сессию просмотренные товары, в виджете читаешь сессию и выводишь. Здесь не нужно искать никаких сторонних библиотек, пишется такое за 15 минут максимум

Comment: Да я уже понял, что легче самому написать